# how to override deny assignment so that I can access the databricks managed storage container?

Tags: azure-databricks

I have a Databricks workspace provisioned in my own azure subscription for my own learning purposes.

I would like to access the containers in the Databricks managed storage account via the Azure Portal UI, however when I attempt to do so:

```
The client 'my@email' with object id 'myobjectid' has permission to 
perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' 
on scope '/my/storage/account'; however, 
the access is denied because of the deny assignment 
with name 'System deny assignment created by 
Azure Databricks /my/workspace' and Id 'myid' at scope '/my/workspace'.
```

How can I grant all permissions to my azure account owner (me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on the managed resource group created by Azure Databricks even if you're owner - it's a resource managed by Databricks, and it prevents direct access to the data because it stores some system information inside storage account.  If you attempt to do this, you will get an error like this:

> Failed to add User as Storage Blob Data Contributor for dbstorageveur7e23e27e4c : **The client '....' with object id '...' has permission to perform action** 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' on scope '/subscriptions/..../resourceGroups/databricks-rg-...-jm5c8b2za1oks/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/dbstorageveur7e23e27e4c/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/f2bc46d3-4aee-4d8f-803d-3d6324b5c094'; however, **the access is denied because of the deny assignment with name 'System deny assignment created by Azure Databricks** /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/...' and Id '99598a6270644ecdacfb23af7b0df9a0' at scope '/subscriptions/....resourceGroups/databricks-rg-...-jm5c8b2za1oks'..

Comment: Thanks Alex - really helpful.   IIUC any databases will get created there by default?  (In fact that is what I was trying to find).  If databases get created there by default, do users like to have separate storage accounts for the delta files in the data lake?

Comment: Yes, by default managed tables are created on DBFS under the `dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/`. But we really recommend to use DBFS only for temp data. For your prod data you can create new databases with explicit `LOCATION` pointing to your own storage accounts.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal),

> When you attempt to access blob data in the Azure portal, the portal first checks whether you have been assigned a role with **Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action**. If you have been assigned a role with this action, then the portal uses the account key for accessing blob data. If you have not been assigned a role with this action, then the portal attempts to access data using your Azure AD account.

From [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal-subscription-admin),

You need to have `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` access to assign Azure roles,

To give owner permission to user go to:

***Subscriptions >> Access control (IAM) >> Add >> Add role assignment >> Owner >> Click on Next >> Select members >> select the user >> Save >> Next >> Review + assign***

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following error: `Failed to add myuserID as Owner for Pay-As-You-Go : The role assignment already exists..`

Comment: doesn't work, I am already owner of the subscription but the deny assignment overrides it